# how to identify which radio button is selected in icefaces?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, icefaces-1.8

I have 3 radio buttons and I want to determine which radio button is selected for further processing.I have tried

document.getElementById("minselected");
also
 document.getElementById("minselected").isSelected();
and

document.getElementByName("min");

but its not working.

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name=whatever]:checked')` returns the selected radio input.

Comment: Note that your server-side framework doesn't affect client-side JavaScript, there are 2 different environments!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using icefaces you dont have to use any javascript tweek to get the check box value.

Try using ice:selectOneRadio component.
Sample code is given below

```
<ice:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection"
    partialSubmit="true" value="#{myBean.myButtonValue}">
    <f:selectItem id="1"
        itemLabel="val1"
        itemValue="val1" />
    <f:selectItem id="2"
        itemLabel="val2"
        itemValue="val2" />
    <f:selectItem id="3"
        itemLabel="val3"
        itemValue="val3" /> </ice:selectOneRadio>
```

where **myBean** is my bean name
and **myButtonValue** is a string variable in bean with getter setter

When you submit the form you will get the **itemValue** in the bean on the variable **myButtonValue**